# Create and simplify links from body of text in PHP

Tags: php

I need to extract all links in a body of text in php and make them clickable. The problem is I can't seem to simplify the text of the link in any way.

I tried using preg_replace_callback but I can't seem to get the trimming function working properly:

```
function trimUrl($url){
    $maxLength = 3;
    if(strlen($url)>$maxLength){ 
        $urlShort = substr($str,0,$maxLength).'...'; 
    }
    else{ 
        $urlShort = $url; 
    }
    return $urlShort;
}

function enableLinks($text){
    return preg_replace_callback("!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i", "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>".trimUrl("$1")."</a>", $text);
}

enableLinks("Visit more work at http://www.google.com");
```

How can I run a second function within the preg_replace_callback that trims the output text?

Answer (score 0):

What if you used a function inside that function. So if the first function evaluates to true then run this next function? And also try using preg_replace_callback in a variable format so its easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using substring(). Where have you defined the variable $str? And, if you do this:

```
$var = preg_replace_callback("!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i", "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>".trimUrl("$1")."</a>", $text);
```

Than can you use a new function:

```
return function($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a more expanded function to achieve this, works on multiple urls with or without "http://":

```
     function trimUrlOutput($url){
        $maxLength = 30;
        if(strlen($url)>$maxLength){ 
            $urlShort = substr($url,0,$maxLength).'...'; 
        }
        else{ 
            $urlShort = $url; 
        }
        return $urlShort;
    }

    function enableLinks($text){
        $text = ereg_replace( "www\.", "http://www.", $text );
        $text = ereg_replace( "http://http://www\.", "http://www.", $text );
        $text = ereg_replace( "https://http://www\.", "https://www.", $text );
        $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
        if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
            $matches = array_unique($url[0]);
            foreach($matches as $match) {
                $linkText = trimUrlOutput($match);
                $replacement = "<a href=".$match." target='_blank'>{$linkText}</a>";
                $text = str_replace($match,$replacement,$text);
            }
            return $text;
        }
        else{
            return $text;
        }
    }

    enableLinks("Visit more work at http://www.google.com");
```

Hope this helps someone.